# Tabulator Dynamic Height with Pagination

Tags: tabulator

I do not understand how to get tabulator to automatically set the proper pagesize for a dynamic height table.
It is giving 2 pages but the amount of rows does not match the height of the table

JavaScript

```
var ActivityTable = new Tabulator("#ActivityTable",{
  index:"id",
  ajaxURL:"/api/getActionLogsData",
  layout:"fitDataFill",
  responsiveLayout:"hide",
  resizableColumns:false,
  layoutColumnsOnNewData:true,
  pagination:"local",
  paginationElement: document.getElementById("ActivityTablePagination"),
  height:"90%",

  columns:[
    {title:"First", field:"User.FirstName"},
    {title:"Last", field:"User.LastName"},
    {title:"Time", field:"CreatedAt",formatter:localRelativeTimeFormatter},
    {title:"Success", field:"Success"},
    {title:"Message", field:"Message"},
  ]
})
```

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <h4>Activity Logs</h4>
    <div id="ActivityTablePagination"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="h-100" id="ActivityTable"></div>
</div>
```

Output
[image: Activity Log Display Page 1]
[image: Activity Log Display Page 2]

Comment: can you create a JS Fiddle or Code Pen that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: does the element holding the Tabulator have a fixed height? there will need to be a fixed height somewhere on the containing element otherwise there is no what for Tabulator to determine 90% of what for its height.

Answer (score 1):

if you specify the height of the table, either in CSS or by using the height option, and don't define the paginationSize option the page size will be automatically set to fill the height of the table.

````
    height:"300px",
    pagination:"local", //enable local pagination.
});```

source http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/page
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).